# Refreshing data fetched with a custom hook after closing a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I'm using a hook to fetch data in my app. The hook looks something like this:

```
const initialState = {
  response: null,
  loading: true,
  error: null
}
const useGetFetch(url, token, user, parser) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, initialState)

  useEffect (() => {
    if(user){
      fetch(...)
      .then((data)=> data.json())
      .then(dispatch(...)) // setting the state here
      .catch((error) => dispatch(...)) // set error state
    }
  }, [user])

 return [state.response, state.loading, state.error]
}
```

Specifically, I'm using this hook inside a form component, to fetch some data to use as options inside a select element.

However, I need to be able to let the user to add new options on the fly. To facilitate this, I've created a button next to the select element. If the user presses this button, a modal will pop up with another form that makes it possible create a new option. This new option is sent to the server via a post request and if successful the modal closes.

The problem I'm facing is that after the modal closes, I have no way of updating the initial data fetched with my custom data fetching hook, unless I refresh the page. Is there a way to make this happen somehow without triggering a page refresh?

My initial hunch was to use a callback function and pass it to the the `useGetFetch` and bind it to the `useEffect` hook. I could then pass it to the form in the modal and call the function after a successful submission, but this hasn't worked.

Another option I'm looking is the `useCallback` hook, but I don't currently understand it well enough to know whether or not it could be helpful.

**EDIT**

Specifically what I did was create a trigger function outside the parent component:

```
const trigger = () => console.log("click")
```

Bound it to the fetch hook:

```
const useGetFetch(url, token, user, parser, trigger) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, initialState)

  useEffect (() => {
    if(user){
      fetch(...)
      .then((data)=> data.json())
      .then(dispatch(...)) // setting the state here
      .catch((error) => dispatch(...)) // set error state
    }
  }, [user, trigger])

 return [state.response, state.loading, state.error]
}
```

And passed it to the child component inside the parent component:

```
const trigger = () => console.log("click")
const Parent = () => {
  // load a bunch of stuff
  // ...
    const { show, toggle } = useModal()

    const [optionsData, Loading, Error] = useGetFetch(
      optionsUrl,
      token,
      user,
      parser,
      trigger
  )
  // ...
  return (
    <div>
      {// ...}
      <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                toggle()
              }}
            >
              Add
            </button>
            <Modal show={show} toggle={toggle}>
              <ModalForm
                show={show}
                toggle={toggle}
                trigger={trigger}
              ></ModalForm>
            </Modal>
           {// ...}
    <div>
  )
}
```

Inside `ModalForm` trigger is called after a successful post request has been performed. After closing the modal, the data is not updated. My guess was that calling trigger inside `ModalForm` would have triggered `useEffect` inside of the `useGetFetch` but it doesn't seem to work like   that.

Comment: Okay as far as i understood the problem is that you want to refetch the data when the user closes the modal? am i right?

Comment: Yes you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If if understood your question clearly i think what you are trying to do is force a refetch whenever user closes the modal.

You can do that by triggering a force rerender inside the `useGetFetch` hook like below:

```
const useGetFetch(url, token, user, parser) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, initialState)
  // calling refetch will force a rerender on the hook
  const [shouldRefetch, refetch] = useState({}); 

  useEffect (() => {
    if(user){
      fetch(...)
      .then((data)=> data.json())
      .then(dispatch(...)) // setting the state here
      .catch((error) => dispatch(...)) // set error state
    }
  }, [user, shouldRefetch]); // note the dep array

 // returning the refetch functions so we can call the refetch() on modal close.
 return [state.response, state.loading, state.error, refetch];
}
```

And thats it for the useGetFetch, now you will use the hook like so :-

```
const Parent = () => {
  const { show, toggle } = useModal();

  // notice the refetch method
  const [optionsData, Loading, Error, refetch] = useGetFetch(
    optionsUrl,
    token,
    user,
    parser
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          toggle();
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <Modal show={show} toggle={toggle}>
        <ModalForm
          show={show}
          toggle={toggle}
          trigger={() => {
            // probably onClose would be better name instead of `trigger`

            // calling the refetch method with empty object, this will cause rerender
            refetch({});
          }}
        ></ModalForm>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Welcome, happy to help :D

Comment: You can also return `refetch: () => refetch({})` from the hook and use it simply with `refetch()` in your component to avoid that weird empty object pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `,` inside useEffect function thats why you getting X is not a function Error

```
  useEffect (() => {
    if(user){
      fetch(...)
      .then((data)=> data.json())
      .then(dispatch(...)) // setting the state here
      .catch((error) => dispatch(...)) // set error state
    }
 //comma here
  },[user]);
```

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect this. The function is now recognized and called, but it does not trigger a refresh on the hook.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a solution by using a boolean but thought there must be a better way of doing this. The accepted solution of using an object is similar but it I do not like the exposed API or look of it `refresh({})` or `refresh(!resfreshSomething)`.

So instead I came up with the following solution:

```
const useGetFetch(url, token, user, parser) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, initialState)
  const [shouldRefetch, refetch] = useState({}); 
  const refresh = () => refetch({});

  // call upon useEffect (() => { ...

 return [state.response, state.loading, state.error, refresh];
}
```

This way you can simple use `refresh();` outside your hook.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

export const useFetch = ({ method, url, body }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);

  const fetchAPI = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await axios({ url, method, data: body });
      setData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.response.data);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchAPI();
  }, []);

  return {
    loading,
    error,
    data,
    refetch: fetchAPI,
  };
};
```